# Custom timezone format in postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have huge csv files that I am copying to postgresql. The csv files can not be altered as they are something the client provides. They can also not be altered from my side because that takes time and the task is very time sensitive. So the only option that has worked for me is the `copy_expert` command from `psycopg2`.

But there is a problem here, the column definition for a particular field looks something like this

```
"submitted_date" timestamp with time zone NULL
```

But my timezone value is something like this: `8/31/2020-16:29:31 PM`

So when copying this value to that definition, I get an error that says

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTimeZoneDisplacementValue: time zone displacement out of range: "8/31/2020-16:29:31 PM"
```

Now the question is, is there a way by which I can define the column using a custom format for the time? Something like:

```
"submitted_date" timestamp with time zone format(m/dd/yyyy-hh24-mm-ss AM/PM) NULL
```

Any help would be heartily appreciated

Comment: No. Your options are:  1) Create a holding table to `COPY` the records into where the column is `varchar`. Then move data from there into the actual tables, using something @Frank Heikens answer to reformat the string. 2) Use the Python `csv` module to walk through the file and replace the '-' with a space.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver great comment. made me realize I could just store it as text and use date conversions to convert it to date whenever necessary. Thanks a lots.

Comment: It would be better to store it as `timestamp(tz)` as you would get benefit of Postgres date/time math and operators.  Also any ordering  would work actually work as expected with a `timestamp(tz)` type. Pretty sure indexing would work better also.